# cast explicito e implito en c#

Tags: c#

tengo el siguiente codigo: que es de este libro https://goalkicker.com/CSharpBook/CSharpNotesForProfessionals.pdf en la pagina 24

```
public class BinaryImage
{
    private bool[] _pixels;
    public static implicit operator ColorImage(BinaryImage im)
    {
        return new ColorImage(im);
    }

    public static explicit operator bool[](BinaryImage im)
    {
        return im._pixels;
    }
}

//Allowing the following cast syntax:
var binaryImage = new BinaryImage();
ColorImage colorImage = binaryImage; // implicit cast
bool[] pixels = (bool[])binaryImage; // explicit cast
```

Mi duda es como realiza cast con 2 clases diferentes

```
ColorImage colorImage = binaryImage; 
bool[] pixels = (bool[])binaryImage;
```

Según tengo entendido, para hacer casting las clases deben heredar de una clase general.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Te estas olvidando de leer la explicacion que intenta darte en esa secion del libreo, si lees nuevamente veras que menciona el uso del `explicit` y `implicit` cuando indica la linea:

```
public static <implicit/explicit> operator <ResultingType>(<SourceType> myType)
```

es por eso que en el codigo de esa clase define

```
public static implicit operator ColorImage(BinaryImage im){...
```

y

```
public static explicit operator bool[](BinaryImage im){...
```

si pones un breakpoint dentro de estos metodo `static`, veras que segun sea el `cast` que aplique ingresara a uno u otro, es alli donde se hace la conversion de tipos

Va mas alla de si hereda o no de otra clase, eso no aplica en este caso porque define esos metodos `static` con el `explicit` y `implicit` declarando como se convierte la instancia de esta clase a otro tipo de dato

Comment: vaya ahora ya entendi, esta parte fue clave para ello <ResultingType>